# Graph not showing up if one vertex has degree 0

Tags: graphs-and-networks

I am drawing graphs in Mathematica and for the most part it has been working all right. For example,

```
a = 
  Graph[
    {1 \[UndirectedEdge] 2, 2 \[UndirectedEdge] 3, 
     3 \[UndirectedEdge] 4, 4 \[UndirectedEdge] 5}, 
    VertexLabels -> Table[i -> i, {i, 5}]]
b = 
   Graph[
     {1 \[UndirectedEdge] 4, 4 \[UndirectedEdge] 5, 
      5 \[UndirectedEdge] 1, 2 \[UndirectedEdge] 3}, 
     VertexLabels -> Table[i -> i, {i, 5}]]
```

displays two graphs. However,

```
c = 
  Graph[
    {1 \[UndirectedEdge] 3, 3 \[UndirectedEdge] 4, 
     4 \[UndirectedEdge] 5, 5 \[UndirectedEdge] 1}, 
   VertexLabels -> Table[i -> i, {i, 5}]]
d = 
  Graph[
    {1 \[UndirectedEdge] 5, 5 \[UndirectedEdge] 4, 
     4 \[UndirectedEdge] 1, 4 \[UndirectedEdge] 3}, 
    VertexLabels -> Table[i -> i, {i, 5}]]
```

does not display anything because vertex 2 has degree 0.

How can I get Mathematica to recognize `c` and `d` as graphs?

Comment: Give the list of vertices as the first argument to Graph.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you construct a [`Graph`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Graph.html) using the syntax `Graph[edgelist, options]` the list of vertices is taken from the edges. Using this syntax it would be impossible to add an edge-less vertex.  When you refer to this nonexistent vertex in the `VertexLabels` option, it is an error.  Then `Graph` fails to give a message and return unevaluated.

Use this syntax instead,

```
Graph[{1, 2, 3, 4, 5},
    {
        UndirectedEdge[1, 5],
        UndirectedEdge[5, 4],
        UndirectedEdge[4, 1],
        UndirectedEdge[4, 3]
    },
    VertexLabels -> Automatic
]
```

[image]